# How to make WebClient's DownloadString perform asynchronously?

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I created a simple hello world program to download data from the web.

```
Private Sub cmdSurf_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSurf.Click
    Dim wb As New System.Net.WebClient

    Dim uri1 = New Uri(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim str = wb.DownloadString(uri1)
    TextBox2.Text = str
End Sub
```

It's pretty simple right. I use a WebClient object to download a string syncrhonously and then I display the result in a TextBox.

Now, I want to do so asynchronously.
Basically, after I download the URI I do something else.
Then after the download is finished, I am doing what it should be.

So I did

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim wb As New System.Net.WebClient

    Dim uri1 = New Uri(TextBox1.Text)
    wb.DownloadStringAsync(uri1)
    TextBox2.Text = ""
End Sub
```

It turns out `DownloadStringAsync(uri1)` is a Sub, so it doesn't return anything.
So, well, what should be displayed in TextBox2 then? What am I missing?

Update: I realized that I should have used `DownloadStringAsyncTask()`.
So I did this:

```
Private Async Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Await downloadStringAndAssignText()
    TextBox2.Text = "I am downloading this. This text will change once the download is finished"
End Sub

Private Async Function downloadStringAndAssignText() As Task
    Dim wb As New System.Net.WebClient

    Dim uri1 = New Uri(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim str = Await wb.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri1)
    TextBox2.Text = str
End Function
```

This is almost correct.
The thing is I want to do this properly so that

```
TextBox2.Text = "I am downloading this. This text will change once..."
```

is called BEFORE `wb.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri1)` is finished.
Also I do not want warning. So how exactly should I do that?

Comment: [Just read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync?view=net-5.0): _When the download completes, the DownloadStringCompleted event is raised. Your application must handle this event to receive notification. The downloaded string is available in the Result property._

Comment: So swap the two lines in Button2_Click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the text of your TextBox before you call the async method that downloads the string. When `Await DownloadStringAndAssignText()` is called, control will return to the calling Thread (the UI Thread), so the `TextBox.Text` is set and shown.

When the async method returns, you can assign to the same TextBox the returned string value.
Your method should return a value, the string it downloaded, not assign a value to a UI element that doesn't belong to this method (its responsibility is to download a string): here the return type is set to `Task(Of String)`.
You can directly assign the return value of the async method to the same TextBox.Text property.

The WebClient object should be declared with a `Using` statement, so it's disposed of when the method completes.

You can directly return the result of `WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync()`, since this method returns a string, the same return type of your method.

```
Imports System.Net

Private Async Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox2.Text = "I am downloading..."
    TextBox2.Text = Await DownloadStringAndAssignText(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Async Function DownloadStringAndAssignText(url As String) As Task(Of String)
    Using wb As New WebClient()
        Return Await wb.DownloadStringTaskAsync(New Uri(url))
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Make sense. I am trying to show my daughter how we can do something else while waiting but your solution sort of works

Comment: It's what this async method is meant to do: you set the text of a Control, then you await an async method. While the *awaited* method runs, the UI Thread is free to continue any other operation. When the async method completes, the operation is resumed to the `await` line and the TextBox.Text is set to another value. It's more or less like using the event of a Timer. -- If you need to perform more than one asynhronous operations concurrently (at the same time), it's probably better to use a static (`Shared`) HttpClient instead of WebClient.